# I dont know why my code is wrong ? and what wrong is it?

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("link1").addEventListener("click", c);
    function c(){
        var a = document.querySelectorAll('.images');
        for(var k in a){
            a[k].setAttribute('class','col-md-12');
        }
    }
document.getElementById("link2").addEventListener("click", d);
    function d(){
        var a = document.querySelectorAll('.images');
        for(var k in a){
            a[k].setAttribute('class','col-md-6');
        }
    }   
document.getElementById("link3").addEventListener("click", e);
    function e(){
        var y = document.querySelectorAll('.images');
        for(var z in y){
            y[z].setAttribute('class','col-md-4');
        }
    }
```

here is my JS code , i dont know what im wrong ? anyone can help ? thanks a lot:)
my demo in codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyRmGy

Comment: Your question should always state what the code is SUPPOSED to do, vs what it ACTUALLY does.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the `class` attribute of the images, they will not be found by subsequent calls to `document.querySelectorAll('.images')`

Set a class attribute that maintains the `images` class:

```
a[k].setAttribute('class', 'col-md-12 images');
```

(If your issue is that the code only works on first link click; you haven't said)

Comment: omg , its working , thanks you very very much :D , do you have any course for learning this ? can you share xD thanks you :D

Comment: @duy I don't have a course, I've just been working with this for ages, and have made most mistakes myself, so after a while you learn to debug your code. If you have no errors in the console, first step is to verify that you're working with the data you think you are working with. First thing I tried here was to throw in an `alert(a.length)` to check that the events were triggered, and the images were being found. When that gave `10` on first click and `0` on the second, you have a pretty good idea of where the problem is.